# how do I know where the branch is merged to?

Tags: git

In a Git repository, there are many feature branches, and they have been merged to other branches.

If I want to find out where branch A is merged to, how do I do? i.e. run a command to print out A is merged to B etc.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Getting the history of merged in the current branch, use the below command:

`git log --merges`

Or check out the logs:

`git log`

Happy Codin'